# Why is the default value for "new" option false in findAndModify() method of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

As stated [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/), by default Mongo returns the original document rather than modified one when calling `findAndModify()`. I would imagine that the updated document is usually wanted if the returned document is used. Is there any particular reason for the default value of "new" option being `false`?

Comment: If you are modifying the document you kind of already know what it looks like after you've modified it, so the old state is arguably the unknown and more interesting return value.

Comment: I could understand a case being made for either `true` (allows the caller to easily return the updated document) or `false` (see the comment from @deceze). In the absence of a compelling reason to choose one value over the other perhaps the decision was as simple as; use `false` since that's the default state for a `boolean`.

Comment: @glitch Then you have to explain why the name of the option is "new" instead of "old". :)

Comment: Indeed though now you're getting into naming which is a trickier proposition than choosing values :)